# Flex is not wrapping elemends correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently working on app and i'm using flex. The problem is flex is not wrapping my components.
I'm using flex, react and styled components. In my other project the same code is working just fine, so I cant really figure it out what's wrong in this one.

```
const Panels = styled.div`
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

const LeftPanel = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60%;
`;

const RightPanel = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 41%;
`;
```

I want the Panels component to wrap left and right panel on mobile, so i want left panel to take 100% and right panel to wrap under the left one. When i set min-width on right panel, it goes down in both fullscreen and mobile.

Short: i want left panel to grow and right panel to grow and go down (wrap).

Comment: Please provide a sandbox link with the code. You can use the template like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rkmnrbye4

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)